# I can't use multiple jquery versions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want use two different jquery version on one page it is my codes:

```
    <!----- mobile menu Starts ----->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/mobile_menu.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
    <!----- mobile menu  Ended ----->
    <!------ The Post slide starts ------>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/post_slide_style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.v1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery_1_5_1 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery_1_5_1(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery_1_5_1("a.gallery").colorbox({rel:'gallery'});
         jQuery_1_5_1("a.dbox").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"480", height:"580"});
         });
    </script>
    <!------ The Post slide Ended ------->
```

The Mobile Menu is work but The Post slide isn't work thanks for helping

Comment: The real question is **Why do you need 2 JQuery versions** ?

Comment: How does post_slide2.js access jQuery. Is it with `$`? In that case it's actually accessing v1.11.0, which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: oh sorry post_slide2.js = jquery.colorbox.js

Comment: @this.lau_ it would actually not have access to jQuery at all (*not `$` nor `jQuery` of any version*).

Comment: @MuhamadKwexa which version do you want the ***jquery.colorbox.js*** to use?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I don't know because I downloaded from a tutorial its the link https://www.mediafire.com/?6fxxudbfsocgg0y

Comment: Please first think what do you actually want to do - don't download scripts from hosting services like mediafire, but use library that is maintained - http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ for example, which supports jquery.1.3.2+, so will work with 1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are passing `true` to both `noConflict` calls.

> **`jQuery.noConflict( [removeAll ] )`**
>   *`removeAll`*
>   *Type: Boolean*
>   A Boolean indicating whether to remove all jQuery variables from the global scope (including **jQuery** itself).

So after those calls you code has not access to `$` nor `jQuery` so you should be getting some errors in your console.

If you want to use the second version of jquery then remove the `true` from that `noConflict` call.

---

In general, though, it is a bad sign when you must use two versions of jQuery in the same page.

Comment: Thanks The problem was fixed...

Answer (score 1):

You should not have 2 different JQuery Versions.

You should use the latest version of [JQuery](https://jquery.com/download/). If you need to support some legacy JQuery API, you addiotnaly need to use the [jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://jquery.com/download/)

From the documentation:

> We have created the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify the transition
> from older versions of jQuery. The plugin restores deprecated features
> and behaviors so that older code will still run properly on newer
> versions of jQuery. Use the uncompressed development version to
> diagnose compatibility issues, it will generate warnings on the
> console that you can use to identify and fix problems. Use the
> compressed production version to simply fix compatibility issues
> without generating console warnings.
>
> There are two versions of Migrate.
>
> The first will help you update your
> pre-1.9 jQuery code to jQuery 1.9 up to 3.0. You can get that version
> here:
>
> The second version helps you update code to run on jQuery 3.0 or
> higher, once you have used Migrate 1.x and upgraded to jQuery 1.9 or
> higher: